# Почему не работает телеграм бот на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import telebot
import random

# Импорт зависимостей
from config import TOKEN
from telebot import types

# Импорт токена
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

# keyboard
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
item1 = types.KeyboardButton("ГЕНЕРИРОВАТЬ")
item2 = types.KeyboardButton("ВОПРОС-ОТВЕТ")
item3 = types.KeyboardButton("АВТОМАТИЗИРОВАТЬ")
item4 = types.KeyboardButton("РЕЙТИНГ МАЙНЕРОВ")

markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4)


# Приветствуем пользователя
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\n Я бот созданный для мобильного майнинга.".format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
                     parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
    with open('word_list.txt', 'r') as file:
        words = file.readlines()
        words = [s.strip("\n") for s in words]

    # Выбираеем рандомные слова
    how_many_words = 12
    frase = (random.sample(words, how_many_words))

    # Ответы пользоателю
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def lalala(message):
        if message.chat.type == 'private':
            if message.text == 'ГЕНЕРИРОВАТЬ':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(frase))
            elif message.text == 'ВОПРОС-ОТВЕТ':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ссылка на FAQ')
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')

        # если удалить *** ниже весь код в *** слетит предупреждаю
        bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А что не работает? Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: просто без ошибок код запускается но не работает

Answer (score 1):

Судя по этому коду, если правильно скопировано и ничего не выдает, то стоит убрать лишнюю табуляцию у каждой функции

```
import telebot
import random

# Импорт зависимостей
from config import TOKEN
from telebot import types

# Импорт токена
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

# keyboard
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
item1 = types.KeyboardButton("ГЕНЕРИРОВАТЬ")
item2 = types.KeyboardButton("ВОПРОС-ОТВЕТ")
item3 = types.KeyboardButton("АВТОМАТИЗИРОВАТЬ")
item4 = types.KeyboardButton("РЕЙТИНГ МАЙНЕРОВ")

markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4)


# Приветствуем пользователя
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\n Я бот созданный для мобильного майнинга.".format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
                     parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
    with open('word_list.txt', 'r') as file:
        words = file.readlines()
        words = [s.strip("\n") for s in words]

    # Выбираеем рандомные слова
    how_many_words = 12
    frase = (random.sample(words, how_many_words))



@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'ГЕНЕРИРОВАТЬ':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(frase))
        elif message.text == 'ВОПРОС-ОТВЕТ':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ссылка на FAQ')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')

    # если удалить *** ниже весь код в *** слетит предупреждаю


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

у тебя bot.infinity_polling() часть функции бота, т.е. бот не запускается из-за того что явно его не запустил.